# Hibernate java.time.LocalTime property saves with offset but reads without

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a `java.time.LocalTime` property and save it within servlet:

```
        LocalTime localTimeFrom = LocalTime.of(hour, minute);
        notificationPreferences.setQuietFrom(localTimeFrom);
        hibernateSession.saveOrUpdate(notificationPreferences);
```

After save I see in database time saved with offset `(notificationPreferences.getQuietFrom().toString() => "00:59" , but in database is 22:59)`. MySQL column type TIME. But when I read this property within other hibernate session I got the time without offset conversion.

```
NotificationPreferences np = 
    (NotificationPreferences) s.get(NotificationPreferences.class, 7889);
```

So the `np.getQuietFrom().toString()` gives me `"22:59"`. Why this happen?

What should I check to resolve time zone conversion?

Comment: may be time zones change when you persist and load. also data base client and your application

Comment: I do this on my PC, so time zones should be same when I save and load. About second - I just set my PC time zone to UTC and restarted SQL client. SQL request result time not changed. Also It not looks like SQL client issue - I just write about it to let know how I checked this behavior.